# Window 10 Mobile - missing caller name after anniversary update

Tags: redstone-builds

After I have updated to anniversary update I am missing caller name event this contact is saved in my contact list. When I call someone or someone calls me there is just phone number displayed. The same issue is in calls history. I have noticed that this problem appears just with some of my contacts, not all of them. The only difference is that contacts that are missing name are from Gmail account. How to fix this behavior?

Comment: I have seen a similar behaviour in Android. When a same number is stored twice with two different names, then the phone will display only the number and not the contact information.